# Why is SQLAlchemy count() much slower than the raw query?

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy with a MySQL database and I'd like to count the rows in a table (roughly 300k). The SQLAlchemy [count](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count) function takes about 50 times as long to run as writing the same query directly in MySQL. Am I doing something wrong?

```
# this takes over 3 seconds to return
session.query(Segment).count()
```

However:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM segments;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   281992 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

The difference in speed increases with the size of the table (it is barely noticeable under 100k rows).

**Update**

Using `session.query(Segment.id).count()` instead of `session.query(Segment).count()` seems to do the trick and get it up to speed. I'm still puzzled why the initial query is slower though.

Comment: I don't know that SQLAlchemy thing, but it sounds as if it would iterate over the result instead of sending a count(*) to the backend.

Comment: The [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/ru/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count) seem to say that the count function simply issues a count statement though.

Comment: Enable logging using `echo=True` parameter when you create an `engine` so see the `SQL` statement actually generated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Using `session.query(Segment).count()` actually issues a `count(*) FROM (SELECT segments.column_1 as segments_column_1, ... FROM segments)` instead of a simple `count(*) FROM segments`. I guess the slow down comes from expanding all the columns.

Comment: Just to mention that these queries have same performance on PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL has terrible, terrible support of subqueries and this is affecting us in a very negative way.   The [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html?highlight=count#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count) point out that the "optimized" query can be achieved using `query(func.count(Segment.id))`:

> Return a count of rows this Query would return.
>
> This generates the SQL for this Query as follows:
>
> ```
> SELECT count(1) AS count_1 FROM (
>      SELECT <rest of query follows...> ) AS anon_1
> ```
>
> For fine grained control over specific columns to count, to skip the
>   usage of a subquery or otherwise control of the FROM clause, or to use
>   other aggregate functions, use func expressions in conjunction with
>   query(), i.e.:
>
> ```py
> from sqlalchemy import func
>
> # count User records, without
> # using a subquery.
> session.query(func.count(User.id))
>
> # return count of user "id" grouped
> # by "name"
> session.query(func.count(User.id)).\
>         group_by(User.name)
>
> from sqlalchemy import distinct
>
> # count distinct "name" values
> session.query(func.count(distinct(User.name)))
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate on the 'terrible support of subqueries' from MySQL?

Comment: the best explanation via google is unfortunately this most horribly formatted blog post, but gets the idea across: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/10/25/mysql-limitations-part-3-subqueries/

Comment: longer post, but near the end goes into more detail about MySQL's planner in this regard: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/

Comment: How do you get the actual int/long count value from the query? If I call count on session.query(func.count(Table.id)), it throws an exception..

Comment: session.query(func.count(Table.id)).scalar() will give you the first col of the first row.

Comment: Is it possible to use this optimized query on a (lazy='dynamic') relationship?  So if I have e.g. `self.relationship.filter_by(some_column=some_value).count()` is there a way to still use the optimized query?

Comment: yes you can say `self.relationship.with_entities(func.count(User.id)).scalar()`.

Answer (score 22):

The reason is that SQLAlchemy's count() is counting the results of a subquery which is still doing the full amount of work to retrieve the rows you are counting. This behavior is agnostic of the underlying database; it isn't a problem with MySQL.

The SQLAlchemy [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) explain how to issue a count without a subquery by importing `func` from `sqlalchemy`.

```
session.query(func.count(User.id)).scalar()

>>>SELECT count(users.id) AS count_1 \nFROM users')
```

Answer (score 10):

It took me a long time to find this as the solution to my problem. I was getting the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError)
>   126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_40ab_0.MYI'; try
>   to repair it

The problem was resolved when I changed this:

```
query = session.query(rumorClass).filter(rumorClass.exchangeDataState == state)
return query.count()
```

to this:

```
query = session.query(func.count(rumorClass.id)).filter(rumorClass.exchangeDataState == state)
return query.scalar()
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question? If an error is thrown, the situation looks completely different than described by the OP

Comment: very curious why this is faster and if it's still the faster option in 2022