# TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable Flask

Tags: python, django-models, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable
```

Here is my code:

```
companies = Company.query.all()
return Company.query(func.count(Company.id))
```

I need to find out number of rows in Company model.
Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Company.query` isnt callable there. If you've already selected all your companies with `companies = Company.query.all()`, why not simply use `len(companies)`?

If you dont want/need to retrieve the data, you can get just the count with `Company.query.count()`

Comment: Thanks YOu DazWorrall for the solutions!

Comment: Using `query.count()` could be a big performance issue (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754994/why-is-sqlalchemy-count-much-slower-than-the-raw-query).