# What is the difference between with_entities and load_only in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

When querying my database, I only want to load specified columns. Creating a query with `with_entities` requires a reference to the model column attribute, while creating a query with `load_only` requires a string corresponding to the column name. I would prefer to use `load_only` because it is easier to create a dynamic query using strings. What is the difference between the two?

[load_only documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.load_only)

[with_entities documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_entities)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11530196/flask-sqlalchemy-query-specify-column-names

Answer (score 81, accepted):

There are a few differences. The most important one when discarding unwanted columns (as in the question) is that using `load_only` will still result in creation of an object (a Model instance), while using `with_entities` will just get you tuples with values of chosen columns.

```
>>> query = User.query
>>> query.options(load_only('email', 'id')).all()
[<User 1 using e-mail: n@d.com>, <User 2 using e-mail: n@d.org>]
>>> query.with_entities(User.email, User.id).all()
[('n@d.org', 1), ('n@d.com', 2)]
```

#### load_only

`load_only()` defers loading of particular columns from your models.
It *removes* **columns** from query. You can still access all the other columns later, but an additional query (in the background) will be performed just when you try to access them.

"Load only" is useful when you store things like pictures of users in your database but you do not want to waste time transferring the images when not needed. For example, when displaying a list of users this might suffice:

```
User.query.options(load_only('name', 'fullname'))
```

#### with_entities

`with_entities()` can either *add or remove* (simply: replace) **models** or **columns**; you can even use it to modify the query, to replace selected entities with your own function like `func.count()`:

```
query = User.query
count_query = query.with_entities(func.count(User.id)))
count = count_query.scalar()
```

Note that the resulting query is not the same as of `query.count()`, which would probably be slower - [at least in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758255/6646912) (as it generates a subquery).

Another example of the extra capabilities of *with_entities* would be:

```
query = (
    Page.query
    .filter(<a lot of page filters>)
    .join(Author).filter(<some author filters>)
)
pages = query.all()

# ok, I got the pages. Wait, what? I want the authors too!
# how to do it without generating the query again?

pages_and_authors = query.with_entities(Page, Author).all()
```