# Is there any difference in speed when using with_entities instead of load_only in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, orm

I am trying to minimize select query execution times in SQLAlchemy ORM. I tried to see the relative execution time for `with_entities` and `load_only`. The database I am working on currently does not have too many entries so I can't really test the efficiency on really large queries.
But these are the execution times.

```
--- 0.0027773380279541016 seconds (load only)---
--- 0.003949403762817383 seconds (with entities)---
```

Now, `load_only` creates an SQLAlchemy ORM object wrapping up the selected columns and defers loading additional columns until specifically called for. `with_entities` simply loads the column values and doesn't form any object. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192428/what-is-the-difference-between-with-entities-and-load-only-in-sqlalchemy) question for the information.

Therefore I assumed that `with_entities` should be marginally faster than `load_only` but I am seeing the opposite here.

Is there any reason for this? Purely accidental or something else?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.