# sqlalchemy query without column

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In postgresql we can get total row count without sending column.

```sql
select count(*) from mytable; -- returns count (total number of rows)
```

Is there any way to so similar thing in **sqlalchemy** without doing raw query

```py
session.execute('select count(*) from mytable;')
```

Comment: That query does not select the count: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/60d91/1 and even throws an error in older postgresql versions

Comment: Possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941416/how-to-count-rows-with-select-count-with-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bad idea, because

- lots of empty rows consume more space than a single one with a `bigint`
- such a query does not conform to the SQL standard, so you lose portability for no good reason

Go with

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable;
```