# SQLalchemy select column and COUNT(column)

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to imitate such query in sqlalchemy: `SELECT col1, COUNT(col1) FROM "table"` (simplified case)

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12942318/11277611), I found how to count a single column, but not a column - COUNT(column) pair.

The answer from a link: `session.query(MyTable.col1).count()`

My current case: `db.query(models.User.places).filter(models.User.id == 10).all()`
(Also want to get a count of places)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will count the occurrence of places alongside the places value, grouped by User id:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

cs.query(User.id, User.places, func.count(User.places)).group_by(User.id).all()
```

Is that what you are after?